# How can I open a web socket with Sails.JS without using a browser?

Tags: ios, websocket, sails.js

I have been trying to open a websocket from iOS with an API developed in Sails.JS running on Heroku. But I am not sure where to point the web socket.

Attempting to connect directly to `ws://my-domain.herokuapp.com` fails with a 503 error every time.

What I have noticed, however, when opening my app in chrome, and monitor the console - I occasionally see this error in the console:

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://my-domain.herokuapp.com/socket.io/1/websocket/2RNf_dS2sjcShe397tEQ' failed: Unexpected response code: 503
```

But almost immediately after, it connects. My question is: where is the socket path on that URL coming from? Is that something that Sails.JS issues upon an HTTP Connection, and is that something I should request in iOS? Or am I missing something else?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest taking a look at: https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-examples/tree/master/SampleAppiOS.  Instead of using web sockets, it uses socket.io.